# as3 movieclip rotation according to mouse

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Hi i'm looking to make a movieclip rotates depending on the angle from mouse. I have this code that seems fine according to what i search on net, but it's not working for me.
Btw, this movieclip has it's own class (Player.as) which is a child of the doc class.
I already put the movieclip on the stage.

```
public class Player extends MovieClip
{
    private var player:MovieClip;

    public function Player()
    {

        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onStage);

    }
    private function onStage(e:Event)
    {

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, on_key_down);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, on_key_up);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,on_enter_frame);
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onStage);
    }

    private function on_enter_frame(e:Event)
    {

        var dist_Y:Number =mouseY -this.y ;
        var dist_X:Number =mouseX -this.x ;
        var angle:Number = Math.atan2(dist_Y,dist_X);
        var degrees:Number = angle * 180/ Math.PI;
        this.rotation = degrees;

    }


}
```

The movieclip rotates when i move the mouse, but not accordingly. I can't find the problem with this, hope anyone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mouseX and mouseY should be **stage.mouseX** and **stage.mouseY** because you want to calculate positions in global space not in player`s local space.